# As3 container issues (container is invisible)

Tags: actionscript-3, containers, layer, stage, addchild

I have a panel which is on the stage (manually added).
When I click on a button, an item is added to the stage dynamically.

I want an easy way to delete all of the added items, so I tried using a container. But when I add the items like this: container.addChild(miniwood)     (I have defined the container in the main class), the items aren't visible!

It's as if the container is below the stage.

Comment: Doesn't anyone know!?

Comment: Have you checked the size of your child? Have you tried to add creationPolicy="all" on the cointainer?

Answer (score 0):

Okay! I solved it!

I forgot to add the actual container to the stage in the constructor!

AddChild(container)